# How can I add Steam Authentication to ASP.NET 7 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, steam

I am trying to add steam authentication to my application but I am facing some issues.
I'm using nuget package called "AspNet.Security.OpenId.Steam".

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddSteam();

var app = builder.Build();
```

The app will start but my page won't even load. There are very few information that i can find about adding that kind of authentication. Can someone explain that for me?

Comment: Your sample code is incomplete. Assuming that `builder` is an `IApplicationBuilder`... are you calling `builder.UseAuthentication()` and `builder.UseAuthorization()` anywhere in your actual code?